# Accessing EMR Log Data Cross-account

Tags: hadoop, logging, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

How do I specify in my JSON config or somewhere else to give BucketOwnerFullControl of log files in EMR?

The situation is that I have an account A that does an EMR job with input from account B s3 buckets. I am using account B IAM credentials to do this EMR job:

```js
"Classification": "core-site",
"Configurations": [],
"Properties": {
      "fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId": "[Account B IAM Access Key]",
      "fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey": "[Account B IAM Secret Key]",
      "fs.s3.canned.acl": "BucketOwnerFullControl"
}
```

This allows me to access the input files and using bucket policies on account A, outputs to account A s3 and I am able to access those files.

However, the log files I am also storing on account A but I don't have credentials to view them (still owned by account B).